# Sed output not redirected to a file

Tags: windows, sed, quoting

I try:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\worknotes\performance\tomcatlogs\livesite\learn>sed
 -e 's/"//g' local07.csv > local07nq.csv
```

But instead of outputting to the file `local07nq.csv` it outputs to the console. What's wrong?

I am using sed / cygwin / windows.

Comment: It may be a quoting problem in the cmd shell: I don't think cmd respects single quotes.

Comment: Since you're already using cygwin, you may as well take advantage of cygwin `bash` as well -- from there this ought to work fine.

Comment: This should work: -e "s/""//g"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes in Windows command prompts (at least the flavors I have used) are often problematic.  You will probably be better off by putting the script (`s/"//g`) in a file and running it that way:

```
sed -f myscript.sed local07.csv > local07nq.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

On cygwin / mintty or cygwin shell, this is fine:

```
sed -e 's/"//g'
```

Instead of using the cmd shell, trying the cygwin shell instead, and get sensible quoting behavior.